# Permission Denied: Raspberry pi MP3 Python 3

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mp3

Noobiest of Noobs here.

Working on a project for a Stem lesson for my daughters class. Using Raspberry Pi, Python 3. Should be simple but I get a "permission denied" when I hit the button. Tried using mpg123 as well but get syntax error with that. I'm so close. Please help me help a 5th grade class.

```
import pibrella
import time
import random
import os
def randomgenerator ():
number = random.randint (1,4)
  if number == 1:
      os.system ('/home/pi/Desktop/Gryffindor.mp3')
      time.sleep (1)
  elif number == 2:
      os.system ('/home/pi/Desktop/Hufflepuff.mp3')
      time.sleep (1)
  elif number == 3:
      os.system ('/home/pi/Desktop/Ravenclaw.mp3')
      time.sleep (1)
  else:
      os.system ('/home/pi/Desktop/Slytherin.mp3')
      time.sleep (1)
while True:
  if pibrella.button.read ():
    randomgenerator ()
```

Error

```
sh: 1: /home/pi/Desktop/Gryffindor.mp3: Permission denied
sh: 1: /home/pi/Desktop/Slytherin.mp3: Permission denied
sh: 1: /home/pi/Desktop/Gryffindor.mp3: Permission denied
sh: 1: /home/pi/Desktop/Ravenclaw.mp3: Permission denied
```

Comment: Linux semi-noob. I don't think it's a python issue, you need to change the file/folder permissions. `chmod +x` or (_not_ advising this but saying as a start position for a search) `chmod 777`

Comment: Can you try running `mpg123 /home/pi/Desktop/Gryffindor.mp3` on the command line first? Additionally, I believe if the everything in the brackets in `os.system(...)` should be in quotes.

Comment: Man you all are fast. If I add mpg123 in or out of the brackets I get SH:1:mpg123: Not found. I am going to spend some time on the permissions of the files themselves and see what I can find.

Comment: `os.system ('mpg123 /home/pi/Desktop/Gryffindor.mp3')`

Comment: When I try that I get "SH:1:mpg/home/pi/Desktop/Gryffindor.mp3: Not found" I guess I do not understand the mpg123 part.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. You were correct but I had not installed mpg123 (SMH) and it was causing the not found error. Works like a charm now. I have always heard how awesome the community here is and boy is it. Thanks again.